# react-select error Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to include react-select into my project but whenever I use the Select component I get this warning and then an error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I am using like this just to test it:

```
import Select from 'react-select';
...
const options = [
            { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
            { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
            { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
      ];
<Select options={options} value={options[0]} />
```

I'm assuming it's a simple mistake in how I've installed it but I can't figure it out. I just ran

```
npm install react-select
```

to install it. Webpack doesn't complain about anything - I just get the error in the JS console when the component is being rendered.

In package.json:

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-select": "^3.1.0",
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue here - https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-gould-mbori?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @UKS sorry the preview is just blank

Comment: Actually the codesandbox does work in Chrome. But it does not work in my project with the same package versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing the file extension of my imported component from .mjs to .js